# Use of consecutive particle の

Tags: grammar, particle-の, nominalization

I want to say:

> The rules on throwing away rubbish/garbage

I thought of three possibilities:

> 1) ごみを捨てる**ことの**規則
>   2) ごみを捨てる**のの**規則
>   3) ごみを捨てる**の**規則

I'm favouring option 1. I think option 3 is just wrong. What about 2? Is that grammatical? Does it sound weird?

Comment: The first one is the only one could be grammatical, but I can't figure out what it means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think #2 and #3 are ungrammatical. I think #1 is grammatical, but I would probably say more like...

> 「ごみを｛捨てる/出す｝**ときの**｛規則/決まり/ルール｝」
>   「ごみを｛捨てる/出す｝**際の**｛規則/決まり/ルール｝」

or more simply (and probably more commonly)...

> 「ゴミ出しのルール」

To use the nominalizer こと, you would sound more natural if you said:

> 「ごみを捨てること｛**についての** or **に関する**｝｛規則/決まり/ルール｝」

but this might be a bit lengthy...

Comment: P.S.「ゴミ出しについての規則/決まり/ルール」「ゴミ出しに関する規則/決まり/ルール」などでもいいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

All three are wrong. Well, the first one is not wrong but is redundant.
You should say:
ごみを捨てる規則
or to be more exact:
ごみを捨てる為の規則